# Select documents where array field contains one of value from given array (array matching)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Consider the following data in Firestore:

[image: Firestore document with array field]

I also have a set of selected by the user he's interested in: `['python', 'sql', 'swift']`

How to get all the documents from my collection where `tags` field contains at least one of tags selected by the user? I'm aware that Firestore doesn't have such operator out of the box. Probably I need to rethink the way I store data somehow? Please point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way you have your data structured, you will need to make one [array-contains type query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) for each of the tags the user is interested in, then merge the results of each of those queries in your app code.

Comment: Thanks Doug. It'd be great if Firestore team would give more attention to add more query operators. My opinion is we (developers, Firestore users) find them too limited and inconvenient. Though I realize Firestore is document-based database and it has certain fundamental restrictions.

Comment: You're always welcome to file a feature request.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support